# NSViewController loadView could not load the 'nib name' nib

Tags: cocoa, nsviewcontroller

I'm a bit stumped.

My app, which is running fine on my Mac (OSX 10.8.4) is crashing on someone else's Mac with the same OS version with the following error message:

```
[NSViewController loadView] could not load the "MFPopoverContentViewController" nib.
```

The nib is there and loads perfectly for me and several other people.

It also seems the app is not outright crashing, but just hangs because it can't load the nib containing an important dialog box (which is needed to go to the next step).

I've been racking my brain trying to figure out why that is.  It's a very simple app, and there's no localization with multiple nibs.

What's interesting is that if I rename the nib to simulate a crash, I get a slightly different error message:

```
[BTIntroWindowController loadWindow] failed to load window nib file 'BTIntroWindow2'.
```

So it seems the error is different — 'could not load' vs 'failed to load' — for some reason.

Anyone have experienced something like this?

Comment: The two most common culprits for me have been a binding that can not be satisfied, or a class the xib wants that is missing. For the first you usually get a more useful warning, but IIRC the warning for the second case was less useful.